MongoDB E11000 duplicate key error on Unique Index for mobile and userId in Mongoose Schema
Problem Description:
I’m trying to design a Client model in MongoDB using Mongoose, which is associated with a User model through a userId reference. I want to allow multiple users to register the same client (i.e., with the same mobile number or email), but ensure each user has their own unique record for that client.
When I attempt to insert a new client, I get the following MongoDB error:
errorResponse: {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: ExpenseManagement.clientusers index: mobile_1 dup key: { mobile: "*****" }',
  keyPattern: { mobile: 1 },
  keyValue: { mobile: '*****' },
}
Code:
Here’s the ClientUser model I’m working with:

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  mobile: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

// Unique index for mobile and userId combination
clientSchema.index({ mobile: 1, userId: 1 }, { unique: true });

const ClientUser = mongoose.model("ClientUser", clientSchema);

module.exports = ClientUser;

clientUserController.js:
exports.addClient = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, mobile, email } = req.body;
  const userId = req.userId; // Assuming userId comes from authentication

  try {
    // Check if a client with the same mobile/email already exists for the current user
    const existingClient = await ClientUser.findOne({
      $or: [{ mobile }, { email }],
      userId, // Ensure this client belongs to the current user
    });

    if (existingClient) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "This client is already registered with you." });
    }

    // Create the new client
    const newClient = new ClientUser({
      userId,
      name,
      mobile,
      email,
    });

    await newClient.save();
    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: "Client added successfully!", clientUser: newClient });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server error" });
  }
};

What I’ve Tried:

I’ve defined the index for mobile and userId combination to enforce uniqueness per user.

Even though the code seems correct, I’m still encountering the duplicate key error when inserting a client with the same mobile number but a different userId.


Question:
How can I resolve the E11000 duplicate key error when multiple users register the same client (with the same mobile number/email) in MongoDB? What am I missing in the schema or query?

That error message indicates there is a unique index named "mobile_1" on the clientusers collection, but that index isn't shown in your code.  Perhaps check with diffIndexes to see if there are any extraneous indexes.
